# No matter how I set the res.format() in Express, the data is always parsed depending on the parse method of fetch(). Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, format

I am not understanding how does the `res.format()` work. I read all the documentation, plus several answers here on stackoverflow, but they don't actually address the part that confuses me.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

     res.format({
         'text/html' : function() { 
             res.send({name: 'romeo'})
         }
     })
})
```

In the above example, I am setting the format to be `'text/html'`, but I am actually sending a JS object.

So, now, in the client side:

```js
        fetch(req)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(content=> {
            //output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(content, '\n', 2);
            console.log(content)
            output.innerHTML = content;
        }) 
        .catch(err=>console.eror);
```

If I use `json()`, the data will just get parsed into a JS object no matter what I send, and no matter what I set the `res.format()` to be. Why? This is what I don't get.

Even if I set the format to be `'application/json'`, I can just send a plain text, and then if I use `json()` again, it will again return a JS object.

And vice versa, if I send a JS object, but use `text()` instead, it will get parsed into text.

So, what exactly does the format do?

Yes, I read that It's supposed to check the `Accept` in the HTTP request header, and then invoke corresponding handler according the `Accept` value, but that doesn't really tell me anything. I am not setting a request header, and no matter how I set the `format()`, the actual format of the data is always determined by the parsing method I choose to use `json()` for JS object, or `text()` for text or html. I don't see the purpose of setting a `format()`.

Comment: The client always decides how to handle data sent to it, all the server can do is tell the client what it is sending

Comment: Are you asking for a way for fetch to automatically parse according to the content type set by format? What do you want to return, JSON or text?

Comment: @PatrickEvans So, even if I don't use `format()`, the server will set it automatically based on the type of the data, right? By the way, the server always turns the data into JSON before sending it, correct? Even if I am sending a plain text, it's still turned into JSON first, is that correct?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Is there such a way?

Comment: You could conditionally call either text or json based on the res content type. res.headers should have a content type header that you could pivot off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.format(object)` is used such that the client can specify what type of content they want returned. The client specifies this information using the `Accepts` header on their request.

To read more about `res.format(object)` visit https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.format

To read more about the `Accepts` header visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept

Below I created a simple example of what this would look like

Server code

```
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.format({
    'text/plain': function () {
      res.send('text')
    },
  
    'text/html': function () {
      res.send('<p>html</p>')
    },
  
    'application/json': function () {
      res.send({ message: 'json' })
    },
  })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port: " + PORT);
});
```

Client Code

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'text/html'
  }
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(res => {
  console.log(res) // <p>html</p>
});

fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'text/plain'
  }
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(res => {
  console.log(res) // text
});

fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  console.log(res) // { message: 'json' }
});
```